# How to split and modify a string in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a string :

```
var str = "123, 124, 234,252";
```

I want to parse each item after split and increment 1. So I will have:

```
var arr = [124, 125, 235, 253 ];
```

How can I do that in NodeJS?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Use `split` and `map` function:

```
var str = "123, 124, 234,252";
var arr = str.split(",");
arr = arr.map(function (val) { return +val + 1; });
```

Notice `+val` - string is casted to a number.

Or shorter:

```
var str = "123, 124, 234,252";
var arr = str.split(",").map(function (val) { return +val + 1; });
```

#### edit 2015.07.29

Today I'd advise **against** using `+` operator to cast variable to a number. Instead I'd go with a more explicit but also more readable `Number` call:

```js
var str = "123, 124, 234,252";
var arr = str.split(",").map(function (val) {
  return Number(val) + 1;
});
console.log(arr);
```

#### edit 2017.03.09

ECMAScript 2015 introduced *arrow function* so it could be used instead to make the code more concise:

```js
var str = "123, 124, 234,252";
var arr = str.split(",").map(val => Number(val) + 1);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var str = "123, 124, 234,252";
var arr = str.split(",");
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    arr[i] = ++arr[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using lodash and in the mood for a too-cute-for-its-own-good one-liner:

```
_.map(_.words('123, 124, 234,252'), _.add.bind(1, 1));
```

It's surprisingly robust thanks to lodash's powerful parsing capabilities.

If you want one that will also clean non-digit characters out of the string (and is easier to follow...and not quite so cutesy):

```
_.chain('123, 124, 234,252, n301')
   .replace(/[^\d,]/g, '')
   .words()
   .map(_.partial(_.add, 1))
   .value();
```

*2017 edit*:

I no longer recommend my previous solution. Besides being overkill and already easy to do without a third-party library, it makes use of _.chain, which [has a variety of issues](https://medium.com/making-internets/why-using-chain-is-a-mistake-9bc1f80d51ba). Here's the solution I would now recommend:

```
const str = '123, 124, 234,252';
const arr = str.split(',').map(n => parseInt(n, 10) + 1);
```

My old answer is still correct, so I'll leave it for the record, but there's no need to use it nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

You may use regular expression to slpit the string

```js
var str = "123, 124, 234,252";
var regex = /\,\s*/
var arr = str.split(regex).map(d => (+d) + 1)

console.log(arr) // Output [124, 125, 235, 253]
```

You may be want to `matches` numbers so:

```js
var str = "123, 124, 234,252";
var regex = /\d+/gm
var arr = str.match(regex).map(d => (+d) + 1)

console.log(arr) // Output: [124, 125, 235, 253]
```