# I need to split a string after a number with dot in Node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, regex, string

My current input...

```
var str = "3.   1203    Copra 4.   1204          Linseed, whether      or      not broken. 5.   1205          Rape    or colza seeds, whether or not broken. 6.   1206         Sunflower seeds, whether or not broken. "
```

what I need output is

```
[ 1203    Copra, 204  Linseed, whether      or      not broken., 1205          Rape    or colza seeds, whether or not broken., .... etc]
```

As simple as I need to split the string where I find number with dot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split and modify a string in NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134199/how-to-split-and-modify-a-string-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 3):

You can handle it with `String#match`.

```js
const str = "1.one 2. two 3.three",
      res = str.match(/(?!\d\.\s?)\w+/g);
      
      console.log(res);
```

Comment: I did not get the input according to my input string if

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression with takes only a group of letters.

```js
var string = "1.one 2. two 3.three";
    array = string.match(/[a-z]+/g)
    
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

To match the items of a numbered list in a string and return an array try this:

```js
var x = "1. Buy bananas 2. Buy a tent  3. Book flight to jungle  4. Eat banana in jungle and 5. come up with better sample for regex"
var result = x.match(/(?!\d\.\s)(\w+\D+)/gm);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your current string - just match the words containing letters:

```js
var str = "1.one 2. two 3.three",
    result = str.match(/[^0-9. ]+/g);
    
console.log(result);
```