# How can we take like an input the keyboard in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my project, I need now to take an input from the keyboard.
The user must be able to enter several words and when he presses CTRL+D you exit the program and the result is displayed.
For example we can enter on the terminal :

```
bob
alicia
cookie
shirley
david
```

We have the following code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

let chunk = "";

process.stdin.on("data", data => {
    chunk += data.toString();
});

process.stdin.on("end", () => {
    chunk.replace(/^\s*[\r\n]/gm,"").split(/\s+/).forEach(function (s) {
        process.stdout.write(
        s === 'bob'
        ? 'boy \n'
        : s === 'alicia'
           ? 'girl\n'
           : s === 'cookie'
               ? 'dog \n'
               : 'unknown \n');
    });
});
```

And when we press CTRL+D we need to obtain this result :

```
boy
girl
dog
unknown
unknown
```

Can you help me please to know, how can I code in order to take the keyboard like an input?

Comment: The `replace()` function is removing all the spaces, so how can you split the result on spaces?

Comment: Where do you set the value of `chunk` before calling `chunk.replace()`?

Comment: What isn't working about the code you've got?

Comment: @HereticMonkey @barmar the right goal it's to write `bob alicia shirley` in the terminal and when the user press CTRL+D we can display the answer like `boy girl unknown`. But here I take a file like an input because I don't know how can we put something we wrote on the keyboard like an entry.

Comment: Sounds like [Reading value from console, interactively](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8128578)...

Comment: Think you I found the solution @HereticMonkey

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://thisdavej.com/making-interactive-node-js-console-apps-that-listen-for-keypress-events/) is an article that explains the basics. I made an example for you down below, you can probably figure out the rest by yourself.

```
const readline = require('readline');
readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin);
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);

let input = [];
let chunk = '';

process.stdin.on('keypress', (str, key) => {
    if (key.ctrl && key.name === 'd') {
        //Handle exit code here
        process.exit();
    }
    if (key.name === 'return') {
        input.push(chunk.replace('\r', ''));
        chunk = '';
        process.stdout.write('\n');
    }
    chunk+=str;
    process.stdout.write(str);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

One way of doing it would to loop input until a certain input is taken.  Pseudo code example:

```
While (x≠q){
    Take input
 }
```

EDIT: Another way, is to not use the return key to use for spacing, instead take the items in all in one input line with a separating comma or space.

```
var str = "123, 124, 234,252";
var arr = str.split(",").map(val => Number(val) + 1);
console.log(arr);
```

I found the above from this question: [How to split and modify a string in NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134199/how-to-split-and-modify-a-string-in-nodejs).
Then you can iterate over the array to find out if it's a dog or a girl!

Comment: I saw this but I don't really know how can I code this correctly and mix with my code

Comment: I have a much stronger background in Perl than JS, so my first thought would be to check the input against a regular expression