# How we can code the case insensitive in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ignore-case

In my project I need to take care about the case insensitive, and I don't know how can I code something like that in JavaScript.

If I write on my terminal, I need for my code to understand the same thing :

```
`BOB
bob 
Bob`
```

My code :

```
       #!/usr/bin/env node

let chunk = "";

process.stdin.on("data", data => {
    chunk += data.toString();
});

process.stdin.on("end", () => {
    chunk.replace(/^\s*[\r\n]/gm,"").split(/\s+/).ignoreCase.forEach(function (s) {
        process.stdout.write(
        s === 'bob'
        ? 'boy \n'
        : s === 'alicia'
           ? 'girl\n'
           : s === 'cookie'
               ? 'dog \n'
               : 'unknown \n');
    });
});
```

The result I need to display is :

```
`boy
boy
boy`
```

I tried to do it with `ignoreCase` but it does not work, can you explain me why please?

Comment: Change your input to lower case with toLowerCase method

Comment: `.ignoreCase` doesn't work because there's no such thing; did you just invent it? You can convert strings to all upper- or lower-case and compare after that.

Comment: Your classmate asked first here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52724411/how-can-we-take-like-an-input-the-keyboard-in-js 8)

Comment: @Pointy no I'am not invent it I saw it on a courses, So can you help me please ?

Comment: @Sorikairo toUpperCase is recommended

Comment: `ignoreCase` is a method on *Regular Expressions*. You can't apply it to collections of strings that you're iterating over.

Comment: @mplungjan I would like to hear more about that if you don't mind ?

Comment: @ShirleyTruffier-Blanc `.ignoreCase` is most likely a custom function that you saw, not a native function.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1308-normalize-strings-to-uppercase?view=vs-2015

Comment: Do you really have backticks around your input and output?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [`String.prototype.toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) on all your strings on input so that when you compare them there is only one way they can be represented.

```
process.stdin.on("data", data => {
  chunk += data.toString().toLowerCase();
});
```

Comment: toUpperCase is recommended

Comment: @mplungjan why?

Comment: @mplungjan are there weird Unicode corner-cases that make converting to upper case more reliable?

Comment: Thank you @zfrisch for you answer

Comment: [answer here, maybe(?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877514/is-it-better-to-compare-strings-using-tolowercase-or-touppercase-in-javascript) This deals with internationalization, but kind of answers the question of "why", specifically the second comment on the original question about characters making a "round trip"

Comment: @mhodges thanks! It DOES seem like a heckuva micro optimization, but I'll take a look!

Comment: @zfrisch Without internationalization, though, toLowerCase will almost always be more efficient since most text is lowercase (less character conversions to make). [More info about that here](https://www.petefreitag.com/item/175.cfm)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140627/javascript-case-insensitive-string-comparison and this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1308-normalize-strings-to-uppercase?view=vs-2015

Comment: @mplungjan That is only when dealing with internationalization and locale comparisons. In general, most string comparisons are more performant with `.toLowerCase()` for the reason I stated above

Comment: Assuming that is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just take the input and force it to all lower or upper case with [`String.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) or [`String.toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) and then compare it to the same cased string:

```js
console.log("test" === "Test"); // false
console.log("test" === "Test".toLowerCase()); // true
console.log("TeSt".toUpperCase() === "Test".toUpperCase()); // true
```

Comment: toUpperCase is recommended

Comment: @mplungjan Why? I've been in the JS world for 20+ years and never heard that. All that matters is that the strings be the same case - it doesn't matter whether it's upper or lower.

Comment: @mplungjan and by whom is it recommended?

Comment: [answer here, maybe(?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877514/is-it-better-to-compare-strings-using-tolowercase-or-touppercase-in-javascript) This deals with internationalization, but kind of answers the question of "why", specifically the second comment on the original question about characters making a "round trip"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1308-normalize-strings-to-uppercase?view=vs-2015

Comment: @ScottMarcus sure enough you can write a quick test using `.fromCharCode()` to try all the 16-bit code points and some of them fail going to lower case and back to upper case. That's news to me.

Comment: @zfrisch it's just a simple `for` loop from 0 to 65535 (probably should stop before then), callling `String.fromCharCode()` and checking whether going to lower case and back to upper case results in the same string as just going straight to upper case.

Comment: @Pointy oh, I see! I'll build that out and check for myself. Seems very odd, but an interesting discussion point.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks. Learn something new every day!

Answer (score 1):

The `RegExp.prototype.ignorecase` property holds a boolean value for whether the the "i" flag is set for a regular expression. This is not a function and does not provide any manipulation operation to the expression or string.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/ignoreCase

What you may want to consider doing is calling something like the `String.prototype.toLowerCase()` function which will convert the string to lower case.

Edit: if it helps, I think you might place the toLowerCase() before the split(), since toLowerCase() is the String's function, not an array's function. And unless you want to later call it separately on each string, might be fastest to do it in one place, something like this:

```
chunk.replace(/^\s*[\r\n]/gm,"").toLowerCase().split(/\s+/).forEach(function (s) {
   // function here
});
```